# Usage of “paradigme” in French vs “paradigm” in English

Tags: traduction, anglais, usage, grec

In the following passage:

> A clear-cut definition of non-classical continuum mechanics can be given only by a negation, so that we need recall what is understood by “classical continuum mechanics”. We understand as classical continuum mechanics the kind of paradigm that was born with the combination of ideas of Euler, Lagrange and Cauchy.

I am interested in translating the sentence:

> (1) We understand as classical continuum mechanics the kind of paradigm that was born with the combination of ideas of Euler, Lagrange and Cauchy.

My effort goes like:

> (2) Nous entendons par mécanique classique du continuum le type de paradigme né de la combinaison des idées d'Euler, de Lagrange et de Cauchy.

Can French "paradigme" signify

> EXAMPLE, PATTERN especially : an outstandingly clear or typical
> example or archetype ([Meriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/paradigm))

like in English ? Thus, can we translate the English sentence (1) by the French one (2)? I am asking because [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/paradigme/57869) does not mention this signification; [Internaute](https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/paradigme/) speaks about it though.

Comment: Je me demande aussi si la phrase anglaise ne serait mal formulée; d'habitude, si ce qui précède ne décrit pas quelque chose de particulier, il faut trouver « paradigm of *something* ». Qu'est-ce qui se trouve avant cette phrase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradigm) is of fairly recent origin and it applies only to science. "It is due to the historian of science Thomas kun (1962); he adopted the word to refer to the set of concepts and practices that define a scientific discipline at any particular period of time;" in his book, *The Structure of Scientific Revolutions* (first published in 1962), Kuhn defines a scientific paradigm as: "universally recognized scientific achievements that, for a time, provide model problems and solutions for a community of practitioners, i.e.,

- what is to be observed and scrutinized
- the kind of questions that are supposed to be asked and probed for answers in relation to this subject
- how these questions are to be structured
- what predictions made by the primary theory within the discipline
- how the results of scientific investigations should be interpreted
- how an experiment is to be conducted, and what equipment is available to conduct the experiment.

> Traduction en français
>   
>    Ce concept est d'origine assez récent et il est applicable seulement à une discipline scientifique en une époque donnée. On doit son apparition à l'historien de la science Thomas Kuhn qui dans son livre, *La Structure de la Révolution Scientifique* (1962) le définit ainsi : un ensemble d'accomplissements scientifiques reconnus universellement qui, pendant une certaine durée, fournit un ensemble de problèmes types et des solutions pour une communauté de spécialistes, selon un ensemble de directives sur
>
> - ce qui doit faire l'objet d'une investigation scientifique,
> - les questions qui ont un sens dans le cadre de la discipline, dans la période considérée,
> - comment ces questions doivent être traitées les unes par rapport aux autres,
> - les implication immédiates de la théorie primaire,
> - comment interpréter les résultats,
> - comment mener les expériences et quel équipement utiliser.

À partir de cette définition il est possible de traduire « paradigm » par « paradigme » dans le sens existant suivant que l'on trouve dans le TLFi:

> « C. ÉPISTÉMOL. Conception théorique dominante ayant cours à une certaine époque dans une communauté scientifique donnée, qui fonde les types d'explication envisageables, et les types de faits à découvrir dans une science donnée.».

Les autres sens ne peuvent pas avoir de rapport avec l'emploi dans la phrase anglaise.